# How do I fix this TypeError?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to python and Google App Engine.  I'm trying to refactor this code from Nick Johnson blog to use webapp2 and python 2.7.  http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-1-Static-serving

Anyways, when I run the code below I get this error.

> TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

I think it may have something to do with the path variable not being defined, but I don't know how to define it.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db

class StaticContent(db.Model):
    body = db.BlobProperty()
    content_type = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(required=True, auto_now=True)

def get(path):
    return StaticContent.get_by_key_name(path)

def set(path, body, content_type, **kwargs):
    content = StaticContent(
        key_name=path,
        body=body,
        content_type=content_type,
        **kwargs)
    content.put()
    return content

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, path):
        content = get(path)
        if not content:
            self.error(404)
            return
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: @systempuntoout gave you the answer but i would not call a method get like this and use it in a get handler. this could cause you issues.

Comment: You've deleted nearly every useful piece of information from the stacktrace. Please include complete stacktraces in future, not just the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because the `get` method of the `MainHandler` class expects a `path` parameter.
You should add *grouping* to the regex in your routing definition to pass the `path` parameter to the `get` method:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('(/.*)', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```